# Data export in power bi -publish on the web (public)

Tags: excel, powerbi, business-intelligence

When published on the web (public) the power bi has limitations in the export of data see link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-publish-to-web

> Limitations
>
> Publish to web is supported for the vast majority of data sources and
>   reports in the Power BI service, however, the following are not
>   currently supported or available with Publish to web:
>
> - Reports using row level security.
> - Reports using any Live Connection data source, including Analysis -Services Tabular hosted on-premises, Analysis Services -Multidimensional, and Azure Analysis Services.
> - Reports shared to you directly or through an organizational content pack.
> - Reports in a group in which you are not an edit member.
> - "R" Visuals are not currently supported in Publish to web reports.
> - Exporting Data from visuals in a report, which has been published to the web.
> - ArcGIS Maps for Power BI visuals.
> - Reports containing report-level DAX measures.
> - Single sign-on data query models.
> - Secure confidential or proprietary information.
> - Shared and certified datasets. The automatic authentication capability provided with the Embed option doesn't work with the Power
>     BI JavaScript API. For the Power BI JavaScript API, use the user owns
>     data approach to embedding.

The code embedded in iframe is not the solution .. any idea?

Comment: Don't use Power BI for exporting the data - export it directly from the data source, which is used by your report instead.

Comment: Please I did not understand your answer. How export it directly from the data source ?? ... send me a image

Answer (score 0):

[Publish to Web](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-publish-to-web) is free and comes with those restrictions.

Full-function embedding of Power BI Analytics is available either through [Power BI Premium](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi-premium/) or the [Power BI Embedded Service in Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/power-bi-embedded/).

Comment: I know the limitations and have the power bi pro license, but could you create a report with power bi report builder and export it?

Comment: Sure.  You could use Power BI Report Builder to export to Excel, Word, PDF, CSV, etc.

Comment: when published the report Power Pro, I requested a license premium

Comment: Yes.  Currently you can only publish a paginated report to a Workspace hosted on a Premium Capacity.  But anyone can use Power BI Report Builder on their desktop.

Comment: @AngelValverde if Premium is too expensive for your purposes you may consider usage of another BI tool, for example in SeekTable with $25/mo subscription you may publish to web 'live connection' reports with exports (including multi-page PDF) up to 50k rows (disclaimer: I'm affiliated with this product).